# For all instances where column a = specific value, check if column b contains text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure if this is doable with Excel functions or if VBA must be used. Column A contains multiple values, all have duplicates (incident numbers). Column B contains alphanumeric text (email subjects).

Going off a list of unique IDs (those incident numbers), the formula should return if column B contains "resolved" in any row where column A matches the value in the list.

Example:

```
100 kangaroo problem    
101 koala uprising    
100 still kangaroo problem    
101 koala leader captured    
101 [resolved] koalas defeated    
102 penguin riot
```

Here, 100 and 102 should return a "No" and 101 should return a "Yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,D1,B:B,"*resolved*"),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! Embarrassed I couldn't figure this one out on my own, but it's been a long day.